# Who are the Yekis?

Tags: communities, yekke

I once heard someone identifying as a "Yeki", or something like that, and the "Yekis" apparently have an interesting musical tradition where they use a different Yigdal tune before Kiddush at each festival, as well as having a special tune for festival Kiddush.  But since I only heard this and never seen it written, it's a bit difficult to find out who the "Yekis" are, if I even managed to spell it correctly.  Anyone know?  Thank you!

Comment: There is a very nice Yekke Shul in Ramot, in Jerusalem, FWIW

Comment: "Yekke"s are often characterized by their meticulous and punctual nature.

Comment: I know I'm digging up a really old thread here, (if I were a better Yekke I would have answered on time), but if you're (still) interested in the different tunes used at different times of the year, Machon Moreshet Ashkenaz puts out a [luach](http://www.moreshesashkenaz.org/luach) every year which includes instructions on what tunes to use when. If you want to hear a lot of Yekke nigunim, KAYJ (Kahal Adath Jeshurun in Jerusalem) has started an [online musical archive](http://www.kayj.net/en/nusach). I can only find a single tune for yigdal in there in the shabbat section, but it has a lot of n

Comment: @Bachrach44, see the comment above yours. :)

Comment: @Bachrach44, thank you for the link -- I'm actually well aware of this website, and if you look at their old site, you can find a few pdfs of old German nusach books.  Of course, the top source for German nusach has to be [Abraham Baer](http://sammlungen.ub.uni-frankfurt.de/freimann/content/titleinfo/853537).  Many Yekkish Yigdal tunes in those books!

Comment: @SethJ, you stole the joke I was going to make!

Answer (score 13):

It refers to the Jewish community of Germany, especially of [Frankfurt-am-Main](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankfurt-am-Main) and its vicinity, which (the community of Frankfurt) was later transplanted to other places, especially the [Washington Heights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudson_Heights_%28Manhattan%29) neighborhood of New York City. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yekke) has more.

Comment: Dang, 11 seconds.

Answer (score 12):

[Yekke Jews](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yekke) are of German ancestry.

They have a number of very strong traditions that set them a bit apart from the rest of "Ashkenazi" Jewry, including, but not limited to, young men wearing a Tallith Gadol prior to marriage, and slightly different cantillation tunes than most Ashkenazim.

Comment: Yekkes FTW!!!!!

Comment: There is a lot in common between yekis and original teimoni minhagim. Both are said to be original yerushalmi minhagim.